# Set size of localstorage for nativeapp created with webapp+webkit

Tags: web-applications, cross-platform, local-storage

I want to create a game and don't want to think about the platform/OS. So I thought if it's possible to create a webapp(html5, css and js) and wrapp around a browser enginge like webkit to create a native app for the different OSs(Linux, IOS, Android, Windows, Macosx, Bada, Windows Phone...).

Is it possible to set the localStorage if I create for example a "browser" with QT+webkit?
Or have I only 5 MB of localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Phonegap (Cordova) [Mobile Web App] ?
http://cordova.apache.org/

PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.

You can make application independent of OS, actually you can use HTML,CSS, etc. and embedded application for multiple os like: Apple iPad/iPhone, Android, Bada, Windows 8, Blackberry, etc, (but documentation don't speak about Linux).

You only have to code once and deploy on all last OS's that I said.

Well, with the 5 MB storage limit I can say you that in Android OS (4.1) I have not 5 MB limit, because I manage 5-10MB databases, and over 70000 to 100000 registers can be managed fine.

If you've planned use webapp (HTML, CSS, etc) with local storage DB, for instance I have not problem with 5MB limitation on Chrome.

I hope help you in your decision.

Comment: I think Phonegap is only for mobile OS. So your have on android a limit of 10MB?

Comment: I haven't needed more storage, but modern browser have high limit on web storage. What do you expect store in database?